# Is there a list of Bitcoin Forks?

Tags: blockchain-fork

I have some Bitcoin from before the Bitcoin Cash fork, and am pleasantly surprised to learn it has some significant value.

I believe there have been a number of other forks as well.  But I don't have a list, or know how to research it, other than general Googling.

Is there any canonical list of forks with information such as Date of the Fork and current value?

Answer (score 7):

There is this list on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bitcoin_forks

- Bitcoin Cash (Forked at Block 478559[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bitcoin_forks), 1 August 2017)
- Bitcoin Gold    (Forked at Block 491407[2], 24 October 2017)
- Bitcoin Diamond (Forked    at Block 495866[3], 24 November 2017)
- UnitedBitcoin (Forked at Block    498777[4], 12 December 2017)
- BitcoinX (Forked at Block 498888[5], 12    December 2017)
- Super Bitcoin (Forked at Block 498888[6], 12 December    2017)
- BITCOIN HOT (Forked at Block 498848[7], 12 December 2017)

Answer (score 2):

This site lists the forks, their state and allows you to search them for funds:

http://www.findmycoins.ninja

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a canonical list, but there are several non-cannonical lists on various websites.  In my search (which also turned up this question) I found 3 that seem relatively comprehensive:

- http://www.findmycoins.ninja/
- https://iconow.net/list-of-bitcoin-forks/
- https://bitcoinforks.io/