# An updated forkcoins tree chart (only blockchains)

Tags: altcoin, blockchain-fork

Where can I find something conveying this information, but up to date?

```
digraph {
  # rankdir = LR;
  splines = polyline;

  # Bitcoin is the original chain.
  node0 [label = "Bitcoin\n~29000$US (BTC - Jun 2022)"];

  # Bitcoin Cash was a first successful fork.
  node1 [label = "Bitcoin Cash\n~200$US (BCH - Jun 2022)", color = "#333333",
         fontcolor = "#333333"];
  node0 -> node1 [label = "Aug 2017", color = "#333333",
                  fontcolor = "#333333"];

  # Bitcoin Gold was a second try to make a successful fork.
  node2 [label = "Bitcoin Gold\n~20$US (BTG - Jun 2022)", color = "#999999",
         fontcolor = "#999999"];
  node0 -> node2 [label = "Oct 2017", color = "#999999",
                  fontcolor = "#999999"];

  # Subsequent forks were tried, but most have been low valued.
  node3 [label = "Bitcoin Diamond\n~.5 $ US (BCD / Nov 2020)",
         color = "#bbbbbb", fontcolor = "#bbbbbb"];
  node0 -> node3 [label = "Nov 2017", color = "#bbbbbb",
                  fontcolor = "#bbbbbb"];
  node4 [label = "United Bitcoin\n~.6 $ US (UBTC / Nov 2020)",
         color = "#bbbbbb", fontcolor = "#bbbbbb"];
  node0 -> node4 [label = "Dec 2017", color = "#bbbbbb",
                  fontcolor = "#bbbbbb"];

  #   There were more forks in Dec 2017 but I think they're all low valued.
  # Ignoring Bitcoin X, Super Bitcoin, Bitcoin Hot.

  # Bitcoin SV was forked from Bitcoin Cash.
  node5 [label = "Bitcoin SV\n~150 $ US (BSV / Nov 2020)", color = "#666666",
         fontcolor = "#666666"];
  node1 -> node5 [label = "Nov 2018", color = "#666666",
                  fontcolor = "#666666"];

  # eCash (previously called Bitcoin Cash ABC) was forked from Bitcoin Cash.
  node6 [label = "eCash\n~40$US/MXEC (XEC - Jun 2022)", color = "#999999",
         fontcolor = "#999999"];
  node1 -> node6 [label = "2021?", color = "#999999",
                  fontcolor = "#999999"];
}
```

[image: graphviz render of the diagram listed above]

Please note this aims discussion on the forks of the original Bitcoin blockchain (forkcoins, specifically), not discussing the codebase forks bootstrapping a different blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, the newest graph mapping forkcoins which spun off from Bitcoin is Bitcoin Magazine's [Map of Bitcoin forks infographic](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/infographic-map-bitcoin-forks). It was published in April 2019, so it will not include newer forks like the upcoming BCH split. It does include the major project forks, but doesn't list all forks (there have been over 40 mostly irrelevant forkcoins).

I looked up a prior project called [Map of Coins](https://mapofcoins.com/bitcoin/) which was aiming to collect the full pedigree of altcoins that forked from Bitcoin's codebase (and other original projects) but it appears to not have gotten updated since 2017.

Comment: what's the upcoming BCH split?

Comment: I never meant codebase forks, tried to edit the question accordingly, but that tree of codebase forks is sweet!

Comment: On November 15th, BCH has a scheduled hardfork. Looks like there are two groups that are taking the project in two different directions.

Comment: SE related facility hints this other page full of good resources: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66054/ :)

Comment: I'm reading news that only one branch of that fork is viable. :)

Comment: So there is now BCHA, while BCHN will keep the smaller name BCH?